# How to apply DoEvents to paste a large range

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, paste, doevents

I'm trying to run a macro which, among other things, copies a large range of formulae and then pastes the results as values into the same range. The VBA for pasting the selected range is:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ 
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Every time I get to the pasting stage, I get the run-time error "-2147417848 (80010108) Automation error: The Object Invoked has disconnected from its clients." This happens even if I have as few applications running as possible.

I came across the DoEvents function and wonder if I could use it in my VBA code. The examples I've seen online so far don't explain how you pass control to the operating system for a specific task - in this case, pasting data as values.

If DoEvents is appropriate to use here, how would I go about it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Rather than copy and paste, you could simply use `somerange.value = somerange.value` adjusting to your specific range.

Comment: If for some reason Rory's suggestion doesn't work or you don't know how to apply it, share the preceding code to receive more direct suggestions (e.g. improvements of your code).